# How to set up virtual hosts properly on a windows machine using Zend Community CE?

Tags: apache, zend-server, apache2.2, zend-server-ce

I have set up Zend Server CE on a windows machine and am having the hardest time setting up virtual hosts. No matter what I do, links on my local machine are showing "localhost" in the path causing all images and links to not work properly.

I have the following in my vhosts file and while the site loads up, most links show "local host in them". Please help.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot D:\zend_server_ce\Apache2\htdocs\domain.dev
ServerName www.domain.dev
ServerAlias www.domain.dev *.domain.dev domain.dev

<Directory D:\zend_server_ce\Apache2\htdocs\domain.dev\>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I added a Tutorial on my Blog about setting up Virtual Hosts on Zend Server Community Edition http://technyooz.com/?q=content/creating-virtual-hosts-zend-server-ce-community-edition-windows